# Energy-term Derivation in the Level Set Formulation of Mumford-Shah

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

In the level set formulation of the piece-wise constant Mumford-Shah energy for two regions (see e.g. • [this](http://www.csd.uwo.ca/~yuri/Presentations/ECCV06_tutorial_partII_dan.pdf) presentation on slide 41 • or [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2gvivFvCs_0&t=3710s) video • or page 4 of [Chan & Vese, 2001](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/902291/?arnumber=902291&tag=1)), the energy function is
$$
E = \underbrace{\int_\Omega \left(\left(I-\mu_1\right)^2 - \left(I-\mu_2\right)^2\right) H\phi + \left(I-\mu_2\right)^2 \operatorname dx}_\text{data term} + \underbrace{\int_\Omega \left\|\nabla H\phi \right\|_1 \operatorname dx}_\text{perimeter penalty}
\text,
\tag{1}
\label{eq:energy}
$$
where $I$ is the image intensity at location $x$, the constants $\mu_1, \mu_2$ are the expected mean intensitites in the two regions that are to be separated, $\phi\left(x\right)$ is the surface and $H\phi$ is the *Heaviside* function of $\phi$, i.e. it is $H\phi = 1$ if $H\phi>0$ and $0$ else.

In all sources that I've looked into (e.g. Eq. (9) of [Chan & Vese, 2001](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/902291/?arnumber=902291&tag=1)), the derivative of the data term of $E$ from Eq. \eqref{eq:energy} w.r.t. $\phi$ is given as
\begin{align}
\delta\left(\phi\right)\cdot\left(\left(I - \mu_1\right)^2 - \left(I - \mu_2\right)^2\right)
\text,
\tag{2}
\label{eq:data_term_deriv}
\end{align}
where $\delta$ is the Dirac delta function, i.e. $\frac{\operatorname d}{\operatorname d\phi} H\phi = \delta$.

**Why is the above the derivative of the data term w.r.t. $\phi$?**

Shouldn't it rather be
\begin{align}
\frac{\operatorname d}{\operatorname d\phi} \int_\Omega \left(\left(I-\mu_1\right)^2 - \left(I-\mu_2\right)^2\right) \cdot H\phi + \left(I-\mu_2\right)^2 \operatorname dx &\\
= \int_\Omega \left(\left(I-\mu_1\right)^2 - \left(I-\mu_2\right)^2\right) \cdot \frac{\operatorname d}{\operatorname d\phi} H\phi\operatorname dx &\\
= \int_\Omega \left(\left(I-\mu_1\right)^2 - \left(I-\mu_2\right)^2\right) \cdot \delta\left(\phi\right) \operatorname dx
&\text?
\end{align}
So where's the integral gone in Eq. \eqref{eq:data_term_deriv}? I'm aware of the shifting property of the $\delta$ function, which would explain the vanishing of the integral, but then the $\delta$ itself would vanish as well; yet, it's present in Eq. \eqref{eq:data_term_deriv}.